# How to filter an object using computed property and props [VueJS]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Firstly, thanks in advance for reading and helping out.

I am a bit lost trying to solve this. I currently have two Dropdown components which renders different options from an object. Im rendering two dropdowns. The second dropdown will depend on the selection of the first dropdown.

Let's say I select "BMW" in the first dropdown, and it should only render "BMW 320i".

The data object looks like this:

```js
{
   "menu":[
      {
         "id":"bmw",
         "name":"BMW"
      },
      {
         "id":"volvo",
         "name":"Volvo"
      }
   ],
   "cars":[
      {
         "id":"bmw320",
         "name":"BMW 320i"
      },
      {
         "id":"volvoc70",
         "name":"Volvo C70"
      }
   ]
}
```

In my template I have two child components which include the dropdown. The **MenuDropdown** includes the **dataContent.menu** content, and **CarDropdown** includes **dataContent.cars** content.

```js
<MenuDropdown :dataContent="dataContent">
<CarDropdown :dataContent="customDataContent">
```

The options of the CarDropdown will change depending on the selection of the first dropdown (MenuDropdown). So I am trying to achieve this by using a computed property:

```js
computed: {
    customDataContent() {
        if (this.dataContent.menu.id === "bmw") {
            return this.dataContent.cars.filter(car => {
                return car.id === 'bmw320'
            })
        } else {
            return this.dataContent
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `filter` method returns an array, index it with `[0]` or use Array.find() instead

**With find**

```
return this.dataContent.cars.find(car => car.id === 'bmw320')
```

**With filter**

```
return this.dataContent.cars.filter(car => car.id === 'bmw320')[0]
```